# Bootable backup to use at another computer once a week

Tags: backup, bootable-media

I want to create a *bootable backup* from my own computer, onto an external USB drive. This will be used to, say once a week, use the computers in my school - I will work there for about 3 hours. When I get home, I want to *write over* these changes to my own computer (without having to keep track of what files I change) so that no information is lost.

How is that done and what software should I use?

Why: I like to work in my school's computer lab. Lots of place and decent computers. But I cannot stand the fact that some of mu customized keyboards via AHK and some of my software does not exist on a regular computer.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear on what you are asking for. Assuming you are on a Windows computer, wanting to sync data from your USB key to your computer, there is a few software you could try:

- SyncToy
- [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)
- [Dsynchronize](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/) (down the page)

For the software part you will have to be more specific, but I think you kind find portable of most used software.

Comment: [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) would be you best guess on windows